# Interpolation of a NURBS curve

Tags: interpolation, splines

Known that NQ=P where N is the Bspline basis function, Q is the control point that we wish to locate, P is the data points given ( the curve must pass through it) is there any way to modify the "N" such that it is rationalized with desired weight so that we can interpolate a NURBS curve through it?

[image]

[image]

I've tried to modify the Basis function matrix and tried to Rationalize it by adding weight and dividing. The result is the curve didn't pass through data points.

Comment: I don't see why this question is specific to the software *Mathematica*. I vote to move this to [http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My apologies, I've edited the question. It originally is related with mathematica. I just didn't upload my code.

Comment: You should post your actual code, not images. You can go to the help centre and read more about proper code formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The procedure for doing a weighted B-spline interpolation is not too different from the unweighted case. I'll use the same point set in the docs, and add a weight vector that gives higher weight to the second and fifth points:

```
pts = {{1., 2.}, {0., 1.}, {2., 0.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 3.}, {5., 2.}};
wts = {1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1};
```

Here again is [Lee's algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(89)90003-1), which I'll use this time to perform chord-length parametrization:

```
parametrizeCurve[pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ], a : (_?NumericQ) : 1/2] := 
       FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^a, Total]];
tvals = parametrizeCurve[pts, 1];
```

Set up the knots for a cubic NURBS, and the basis function matrix:

```
m = 3;
knots = Join[ConstantArray[0, m + 1], MovingAverage[ArrayPad[tvals, -1], m],
             ConstantArray[1, m + 1]];
bas = Table[BSplineBasis[{m, knots}, j - 1, tvals[[i]]],
            {i, Length[pts]}, {j, Length[pts]}];
```

Up to this point, the proceedings have been exactly the same as with the unweighted case. For comparison purposes, let's generate the unweighted control points:

```
cn = LinearSolve[bas, pts];
```

Now, spot the differences between the previous snippet and the following snippet for the weighted control points:

```
cw = LinearSolve[bas, bas.wts pts]/wts;
```

Now, let's show the points along with the unweighted (red) curve and the weighted (blue) curve:

```
Graphics[{{Red, BSplineCurve[cn, SplineDegree -> m, SplineKnots -> knots]},
          {Blue, BSplineCurve[cw, SplineDegree -> m, SplineKnots -> knots, 
                              SplineWeights -> wts]},
          {Green, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]}},
         PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 13/4}}]
```

[image: unweighted and weighted B-spline]

Note the sharper turns in the blue curve. You should now be able to see why weighted interpolations are in fact not that commonly done.

Comment: Dear J.M. I would like to ask you a question. For the *built-in* `BSplineBasis`, what is the default `knots` in the `BSplineBasis[d,n,x]`? For instance, By the result of `BSplineBasis[3,1,x] // PiecewiseExpand`, I guess the *default* `knots` is `knots ={1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4,5/4,5/4,5/4,5/4}`. However, when I execute the code `BSplineBasis[{3,knots}},1,x] // PiecewiseExpand`, which gives a different result from `BSplineBasis[3,1,x] // PiecewiseExpand` .Namely, my guess is wrong. THX.

Comment: @Shutao, clamped uniform knots over $[0,1]$ are used by default, if memory serves.

Comment: According @J. M. to your description, is it the defaut `knots={0,0,0,0,1/4,2/4,3/4,1,1,1,1}`? But the result of `BSplineBasis[3,1,x] // PiecewiseExpand` is different from `BSplineBasis[{3,knots}},1,x] // PiecewiseExpand`. Maybe I have a wrong understanding:-)

Comment: I do not have access to a computer right now to check. Let me get back to you when I can do so.

Comment: OK, @J. M.　THX a lot　:)